# Discord.js: Pushing to array is combining strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I am editing an embed message to update users that have "signed up" to a list by reacting. However, after my array length gets to 2, it begins combining the strings of the entire array before adding the new entry. Here is my code:

```js
let newParticipant = getNickname(guildMembers) || user.tag;

//this line exists because "value" cannot be empty in an embed field
//so this removes the placeholder on the first entry

if (newEmbed.fields[2].value[0] === "0") {
    newEmbed.fields[2].value = [
        `${newEmbed.fields[2].value.length}. ${newParticipant}`,
    ];
} else {
    let participants = [newEmbed.fields[2].value];

    let newEntry = participants.length + 1 + ". " + newParticipant;
    participants.push(newEntry);

    newEmbed.fields[2] = { name: "Participants", value: participants };
    console.log(newEmbed.fields[2].value);
}
```

However this is the output I'm getting after 3 reactions:

```js
[ '1. Cardinal' ]
[ '1. Cardinal', '2. Cardinal' ]
[ '1. Cardinal\n2. Cardinal', '2. Cardinal' ]
```

Is this something native to discord? Is my logic bad? I've tried using a spread operator when bringing in the array and several other things...

Comment: it happens because `newEmbed.fields[2].value` returns *one* single string. But tbh I don't see how that would be a problem because it is marked with a line break so you can just use it. Have you tried just doing what you wanted to do?

Comment: I am trying to make it work with an array so I can incrementally increase the number so it's a numbered list.

Comment: well you could split the string you get from the embed so that you have an array with more elements

Comment: that solution works! posted below. thank you. good lesson in KISS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked. thank you Worthy Alpaca. I still wish I knew what exactly was happening lol.

```
let participants = newEmbed.fields[2].value;
        let num = participants.split("\n").length;
        let newEntry = `\n${num + 1}. ${newParticipant}`;
        participants += newEntry;

        newEmbed.fields[2] = { name: "Participants", value: participants };
        console.log(newEmbed.fields[2].value);
```

Comment: well, `newEmbed.fields[2].value` returns one string. Because you set that string into an array, that array only has one element. Because you want to increment the number based on the number of elemtents in the array you need to split it to make sure all your lines are registered as individual elements.